# Eigen 3: Runtime 'EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE' error?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, eigen

I am using Eigen library to build a simple forward/inverse kinematics library. I have written the code for the forward kinematics part but the compilation results in an error;

```
EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE
```

The problem is the error does not specify where the error has occurred in my original instead it takes me to matrix.h file of Eigen. How do I debug Eigen related issues like these?

This is my class definition and implementation code.

Header file

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class RobotArm
{

public:
   RobotArm(bool upperLevel);
   Vector3d forwardKinematics(VectorXd twistAngle);
   VectorXd inversekinematics();
void homeArm();

private:
   Vector4d linkLengthUpper = {5, 5, 5, 5};
   Vector3d linkLengthLower = {5, 5, 5};
   Vector4d alphaUpper = {90, 90, 0, 0};
   Vector4d alphaLower = {90, 90, 0};
   double linkOffset = 0;
   VectorXd linkLength;
   VectorXd alpha;
   Vector4d twistAngle;
   double xPos, yPos, zPos;
   MatrixX4d T;
   MatrixX4d H;
   Vector3d pos;
   MatrixX4d substitute(double theta, double alpha, double a, double d);
};

#endif /* defined(____RobotArm__) */
```

Implementation file

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

RobotArm::RobotArm(bool upperLevel)
{
if(upperLevel)
{
    cout << "Upper level manipulator object created" << endl;
    RobotArm::linkLength.resize(RobotArm::linkLengthUpper.size());
    RobotArm::linkLength = RobotArm::linkLengthUpper;
    RobotArm::alpha.resize(RobotArm::alphaUpper.size());
    RobotArm::alpha = RobotArm::alphaUpper;

}
else
{
    cout << "Lower level manipulator object created" << endl;
    RobotArm::linkLength = RobotArm::linkLengthUpper;
    RobotArm::alpha = RobotArm::alphaLower;
}

}

Vector3d RobotArm::forwardKinematics(VectorXd twistAngle)
{
MatrixX4d H;
H = MatrixX4d::Constant(4,4,1);

//Update current link parameters
for (int i = 0; i < twistAngle.size(); i++)
{
    RobotArm::H *= substitute(twistAngle[i], alpha[i], linkLength[i],   linkOffset);
}

pos(0,0) = H(0,3);
pos(1,0) = H(1,3);
pos(1,0) = H(2,3);

return pos;
}

MatrixX4d RobotArm::substitute(double theta, double alpha, double a, double d)
{
RobotArm::T << cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0, a,
     (sin(theta)*cos(alpha)), (cos(theta)*cos(alpha)), -sin(alpha), (-      sin(alpha)*d),
     (sin(theta)*sin(alpha)),(cos(theta)*sin(alpha)), cos(alpha), (cos(alpha)*d),
     0, 0, 0, 1;

return T;
}
```

Basically the program should return coordinate points `pos(x,y,z)` when `RobotArm::forwardKinematics({theta_1,theta_2,theta_3,theta_4})` is called with `theta` angle arguments. The math behind the coding is correct. I am not really sure how to debug the error shown by Eigen. First time using Eigen library, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector4d alphaLower = {90, 90, 0};` does not have 4 items, either add a fourth or change to `Vector3d`.  Also if you know that `twistAngle` is a `Vector4d` make it that.  Don't use `VectorXd` (dynamic) unless you have to.

If you're using Visual Studio to compile this look at the "Output" tab to see which line in your source caused the error.  The "Error List" doesn't provide all the details.

Comment: Thank you. But twistAngle sometimes takes 3 variables only, thats why I used dynamic memory allocation. What do I do in this case?. I am using Xcode for this project development. Is there any way I can view errors/output on Xcode? The console window does not display any errors. Thank again.

Comment: @VinokanthVelu I don't use Xcode so I don't know how to get the full error message out of it.  But if their support forums and people can't help I'd be shocked.  As for 3 or 4 elements, you're fine doing what you did.  I would make an overloaded version with `Vector3d` and `Vector4d`, but that's just my style.

Comment: Thank you. I will raise a query on the support forum. Also can you pls expand on the overloading part. I do understand you can overload a function. But how can I overload twistAngle?, since its a variable. Thanks.

Comment: @VinokanthVelu Yes overload the function, not the variable, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 3):

That `ASSERT`, which gives you the error, is done at least to check that you try to initialize matrices and vectors to be of the correct size. I think you should also get more information like `matrix.h: error static assertion failed: THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE`.

Given this information and checking your initializations there is at least one bug in the header file:

```
Vector4d alphaLower = {90, 90, 0};
```

The vector is defined to be a four component vector, but you only give three components.